# Adding different y-axis name to all different chart in synchronous chart Highchart

Tags: javascript, highcharts

I'm trying the below synchronous chart to have different Y-axis name for each chart.I searched a lot but didn't find any answers.
If any help with this will be appreciated.

```js
/*
The purpose of this demo is to demonstrate how multiple charts on the same page
can be linked through DOM and Highcharts events and API methods. It takes a
standard Highcharts config with a small variation for each data set, and a
mouse/touch event handler to bind the charts together.
*/



/**
 * In order to synchronize tooltips and crosshairs, override the
 * built-in events with handlers defined on the parent element.
 */
$('#container').bind('mousemove touchmove touchstart', function (e) {
var chart,
    point,
    i,
    event;

for (i = 0; i < Highcharts.charts.length; i = i + 1) {
    chart = Highcharts.charts[i];
    event = chart.pointer.normalize(e.originalEvent); // Find coordinates within the chart
    point = chart.series[0].searchPoint(event, true); // Get the hovered point

    if (point) {
        point.highlight(e);
    }
}
});
/**
 * Override the reset function, we don't need to hide the tooltips and crosshairs.
 */
Highcharts.Pointer.prototype.reset = function () {
return undefined;
};

/**
 * Highlight a point by showing tooltip, setting hover state and draw crosshair
 */
Highcharts.Point.prototype.highlight = function (event) {
this.onMouseOver(); // Show the hover marker
this.series.chart.tooltip.refresh(this); // Show the tooltip
this.series.chart.xAxis[0].drawCrosshair(event, this); // Show the crosshair
};

/**
 * Synchronize zooming through the setExtremes event handler.
 */
function syncExtremes(e) {
var thisChart = this.chart;

if (e.trigger !== 'syncExtremes') { // Prevent feedback loop
    Highcharts.each(Highcharts.charts, function (chart) {
        if (chart !== thisChart) {
            if (chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes) { // It is null while updating
                chart.xAxis[0].setExtremes(e.min, e.max, undefined, false, { trigger: 'syncExtremes' });
            }
        }
    });
}
}

// Get the data. The contents of the data file can be viewed at
// https://github.com/highcharts/highcharts/blob/master/samples/data/activity.json
$.getJSON('https://www.highcharts.com/samples/data/jsonp.php?filename=activity.json&callback=?', function (activity) {
$.each(activity.datasets, function (i, dataset) {

    // Add X values
    dataset.data = Highcharts.map(dataset.data, function (val, j) {
        return [activity.xData[j], val];
    });

    $('<div class="chart" style="width:200px;float:left;">')
        .appendTo('#container')
        .highcharts({
            chart: {
                marginLeft: 40, // Keep all charts left aligned
                spacingTop: 20,
                spacingBottom: 20
            },
            title: {
                text: dataset.name,
                align: 'left',
                margin: 0,
                x: 30
            },
            credits: {
                enabled: false
            },
            legend: {
                enabled: false
            },
            xAxis: {
                crosshair: true,
                events: {
                    setExtremes: syncExtremes
                },
                labels: {
                    format: '{value} km'
                }
            },
            yAxis: {
                title: {
                    text: null
                }
            },
            tooltip: {
                positioner: function () {
                    return {
                        x: this.chart.chartWidth - this.label.width, // right aligned
                        y: -1 // align to title
                    };
                },
                borderWidth: 0,
                backgroundColor: 'none',
                pointFormat: '{point.y}',
                headerFormat: '',
                shadow: false,
                style: {
                    fontSize: '18px'
                },
                valueDecimals: dataset.valueDecimals
            },
            series: [{
                data: dataset.data,
                name: dataset.name,
                type: dataset.type,
                color: Highcharts.getOptions().colors[i],
                fillOpacity: 0.3,
                tooltip: {
                    valueSuffix: ' ' + dataset.unit
                }
            }]
        });
});
});
```

```css
.chart {
    min-width: 320px;
    max-width: 800px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 0 auto;
}

#container {
 min-width: 310px;
 max-width: 400px;
 margin: 0 auto
}
</style>
<!-- http://doc.jsfiddle.net/use/hacks.html#css-panel-hack -->
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1" />
<style>
```

```html
<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.1.1.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://code.highcharts.com/highcharts.js"></script>

<div id="container"></div>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

One possible way of doing this would be to do this, create an array of the yAxis titles:

```
var yAxisName = ['km/h', 'meters', 'bpm'];
```

Uncomment the indenting (or the axis title will not be shown:

```
chart: {
// marginLeft: 40,
...
}
```

And finally setting the actual title:

```
 yAxis: {
   title: {
     text: yAxisName[i]
   }
 }
```

**Working example:** http://jsfiddle.net/ewolden/th26ay3m/